# Program executes Else statement after If statement

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.in;
public class AI_Core {

     /**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Input;
    String HOY_Input;
    Scanner Command = new Scanner(in);
    Scanner HOY_Response = new Scanner(in);
    out.println("Hello Sir, how can I help you?");
    while(true){
        Input = Command.nextLine();
        if((Input.equals("Hello")) || (Input.equals("Hey M"))) {
            out.println("Hello Sir, how are you?");
            HOY_Input = HOY_Response.nextLine();
            if((HOY_Input.equals("Great!")) || (HOY_Input.equals("Alright"))) {
                out.println("Glad to hear it sir.");
            }
            if((HOY_Input.equals("Not so good")) || (HOY_Input.equals("Been better"))) {
                out.println("I'm sorry to hear that sir, just let me know if I can help in any way.");
            }
        }
        if(Input.equals("exit")) {
            out.println("Goodbye Sir.");
            //out.wait();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            out.println("I'm sorry sir, but I don't quite understand the term: ");
            out.print(Input);
            out.print(", could you please check your spelling and try again?");
        }
    }
}

}
```

The Else statement executes after the If statement, as shown in the console:

> Hello Sir, how can I help you?
>   Hey M
>   Hello Sir, how are you?
>   Great!
>   Glad to hear it sir.
>   I'm sorry sir, but I don't quite understand the term: Hey M, could you please check your spelling and try again?

Comment: Put an `else` before the second `if`. Your logic would enter the first one as its own `if` block, and then treat the next as a separate `if-else` block.

Comment: You have two scanners on System.in. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your else statement only refers to the if statement right before it. The very first if statement is all on it's own. The else portion will execute as long as the input isn't 'exit'.

You need an `else if` to connect all three statements so that only one will execute:

```
else if(Input.equals("exit")) {
```

This page might help:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 3):

When you say `if(Input.equals("exit"))`, you've started another `if`.  The `Input` doesn't match "exit", so the else is executed.

It looks like you want only one of the 3 total cases executed.  In that case, you want `else if`, to connect it to the first `if`:

```
else if(Input.equals("exit")) {
```

This way, `I'm sorry sir, but I don't quite understand the term:` will only be printed if the first two `if` statements both yield `false`.

Comment: It does execute the If statement that as it should, but then it also execs the Else statement